# Is it possible for EU passport holders to cross the border Laos-Myanmar somewhere conventiently overland?

Tags: visas, borders, eu-citizens, laos, myanmar

Is it possible for EU passport holders to cross the border Laos-Myanmar somewhere conveniently overland?

I would like to go from Laos to Myanmar by land if it's possible to go there now.

Does anyone know of a border crossing that would work? Preferably with visa on arrival or day pass.

Comment: This thread on the Lonely Planet forum indicates that there's one border crossing that's technically open, but in practice closed and very inconveniently located to boot: https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-south-east-asia-mainland/myanmar/new-land-border-crossing-myanmar-laos?page=2

Comment: I am not sure if it is makes a difference, but you should state your citizenship. You can not take it for granted that Lao and Burmese immigration rules are the same for citizens of all EU countries.